# Numbered runners finishing with their shirt numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, fixed-points, derangements

> $N$ equally able runners enter a race. Each has an assigned shirt
> number from $1$ to $N$. What is the probability that exactly $m$
> runners will have a finishing position equal to their shirt number?

I think the key to the problem would be to find the general probability of none of $N-m$ runners finishing with their numbers, and working from there. However, I'm unable to figure it out. The tricky part is that when you count the number of permutations, it always comes down to a possible situation when the last runner has no choice and you got stuck.

Comment: No runners with the correct number is related to *derangements*.  A given number with the correct number is related to *rencontres numbers*

Comment: For each $m$ you want to multiply the number of $m$-subsets of $N$ by the number of "derangements" of $N-m$, and then divide that product by $N!$.

Comment: @Henry I've never heard of this term, but looking at Wikipedia this will essentially solve the problem!

Comment: This is a problem about [partial derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers).